# How do you join on the same table, twice, in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. One (domains) has domain ids, and domain names (dom_id, dom_url).

the other contains actual data, 2 of which columns require a TO and FROM domain names. So I have 2 columns rev_dom_from and rev_dom_for, both of which store the domain name id, from the domains table.

Simple.

Now I need to actually display both domain names on the webpage. I know how to display one or the other, via the LEFT JOIN domains ON reviews.rev_dom_for = domains.dom_url query, and then you echo out the dom_url, which would echo out the domain name in the rev_dom_for column.

But how would I make it echo out the 2nd domain name, in the dom_rev_from column?

Answer (score 187, accepted):

you'd use another join, something along these lines:

```
SELECT toD.dom_url AS ToURL, 
    fromD.dom_url AS FromUrl, 
    rvw.*

FROM reviews AS rvw

LEFT JOIN domain AS toD 
    ON toD.Dom_ID = rvw.rev_dom_for

LEFT JOIN domain AS fromD 
    ON fromD.Dom_ID = rvw.rev_dom_from
```

***EDIT***:

All you're doing is joining in the table multiple times.   Look at the query in the post: it selects the values from the Reviews tables (aliased as rvw), that table provides you 2 references to the Domain table (a FOR and a FROM).

At this point it's a simple matter to left join the Domain table to the Reviews table. Once (aliased as toD) for the FOR, and a second time (aliased as fromD) for the FROM.

Then in the SELECT list, you will select the DOM_URL fields from both LEFT JOINS of the DOMAIN table, referencing them by the table alias for each joined in reference to the Domains table, and alias them as the ToURL and FromUrl.

For more info about aliasing in SQL, read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_alias.asp).

Comment: the trick is that you've identified each JOIN with a name 'AS to' and 'AS from' so that you can use them in the SELECT.

Comment: using a non keyword for a table name would clarify.  in addition, use the "as" keyword when aliasing.

Comment: Forgive me, but I still dont understand how this is supposed to work. The 2 tables are: domains (dom_id, dom_url), and reviews (rev_id, rev_dom_from, rev_dom_for). If someone could write the exact query so I cna get the hang of it, that would be great, because I have no idea what I have to edit.

Comment: Think of the aliases as referencing rows in the table, not the table itself.  By analogy, in a loop like "for(i=0;i<max;i++)" the variable i is an iterating value, it's not the loop itself.

Comment: I did not know you could do this in SQL, Gracias.

Answer (score 8):

Given the following tables..

```
Domain Table
dom_id | dom_url

Review Table
rev_id | rev_dom_from | rev_dom_for
```

Try this sql... (It's pretty much the same thing that Stephen Wrighton wrote above)
The trick is that you are basically selecting from the domain table twice in the same query and joining the results.

```
Select d1.dom_url, d2.dom_id from
review r, domain d1, domain d2
where d1.dom_id = r.rev_dom_from
and d2.dom_id = r.rev_dom_for
```

If you are still stuck, please be more specific with exactly it is that you don't understand.

Answer (score -3):

Read this and try, this will help you:

**Table1**

```
column11,column12,column13,column14
```

**Table2**

```
column21,column22,column23,column24


SELECT table1.column11,table1.column12,table2asnew1.column21,table2asnew2.column21 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 AS table2asnew1 ON table1.column11=table2asnew1.column21  INNER TABLE table2 as table2asnew2 ON table1.column12=table2asnew2.column22
```

`table2asnew1` is an instance of table 2 which is matched by `table1.column11=table2asnew1.column21`

and

`table2asnew2` is another instance of table 2 which is matched by `table1.column12=table2asnew2.column22`