# how to write this mysql join

Tags: mysql, database, select, join

I have the following table

```
mysql> desc items;
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| code              | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name              | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| price             | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ingredient_id     | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ingredient_id2    | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| ingredient_id3    | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and my ingredients table

```
mysql> desc ingredients;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and `ingredient_id, ingredient_id2, ingredient_id3` columns are foreign keys of 'ingredients' table, my requirement is to create a select query to display items and ingredients as follows

```
select id, code, name, price, name as ingredient_name1, name as ingredient_name2, name as ingredient_name3
```

But I dont know how to join the same table 3 times, can someone help me to understand this join condition

Comment: "how to join the same table 3 times" --- you just join the same table 3 times, giving different aliases. There is no special magic in joining table to itself

Comment: Basic duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199953/how-do-you-join-on-the-same-table-twice-in-mysql

Comment: fyi: the items table is not normalized. What would you do if an item had more than 3 ingredients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY

```
SELECT i.id, i.name, i.code, i.price, 
       ig1.name AS igName1,ig2.name AS igName2,ig3.name as igName3
FROM items i 
INNER JOIN ingredients ig1 ON ig1.id=i.ingredient_id
INNER JOIN ingredients ig2 ON ig2.id=i.ingredient_id2
INNER JOIN ingredients ig3 ON ig3.id=i.ingredient_id3
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select items.id, 
code, 
name, 
price, 
in_1.name as ingredient_name1, 
in_2.name as ingredient_name2, 
in_3.name as ingredient_name3
from items
  join ingredients as in_1 on items.ingredient_id = in_1.id
  join ingredients as in_2 on items.ingredient_id2 = in_2.id        
  join ingredients as in_3 on items.ingredient_id3 = in_3.id
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I got the following error when executing the above code - ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous, anyway thanks a lot for the answer :D

Comment: Fixed the ambiguity in the column list.

Comment: cool, thanks brian, I had to add 'items' to all the select columns to get it to working, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hi You can use the same table with different alias.

ingredients AS In1
ingredients AS In2
ingredients AS In3

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
select it.id, it.code, it.name, it.price,
    ing1.name as name1, ing2.name as name2, ing3.name as name3
from items it, ingredients ing1, ingredients ing2, ingredients ing2
where it.ingredient_id = ing1.id
    and it.ingredient_id2 = ing2.id
    and it.ingredient_id3 = ing3.id
```