# mysql joining two same columns

Tags: mysql

I know title is a bit confusing but i dont know how to name it better.
I have tables like that:

products:

```
product_id | product_name | product_category1 | product_category2
```

categories

```
category_id | category_name
```

I want to select record which looks like that:

> product_id | product_name | category_name | subcategory_name (where category is category1 and subcategory is category2)

So what i need is to join 2 columns where each column is the "category_name" column but `category_name` has to have id saved in `product_category1` and `subcategory_name` has to have id saved in `product_category2`

I tried a lot of things, but i am really stuck. I cant even paste my concept because, currently, i dont have one.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199953/how-do-you-join-on-the-same-table-twice-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to join products and categories twice, using different aliases for the `categories` table in the two joins. Something like:

```
SELECT prd.product_id, prd.product_name,cat.category_name,subcat.category_name
FROM products AS prd
JOIN categories AS cat ON cat.category_id = prd.product_category1
JOIN categories AS subcat ON subcat.category_id = prd.product_category2
```