# MySQL Combine 2 rows into one

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables like that:

```
Item
-------------------------------------
|ID | ImageURLID | BannerImageURLID |
-------------------------------------
| 1 |     1      |        2         |
| 2 |     3      |        4         |
| 3 |     5      |        6         |
-------------------------------------

ImageURL
--------------------------------------
|ID |   iOSURL    |   iOSRetinaURL   |
--------------------------------------
| 1 | www.test.at |   www.testR.at   |
| 2 | www.bann.at |   www.bannR.at   |
| 3 | www.test.at |   www.testR.at   |
| 4 | www.bann.at |   www.bannR.at   |
| 5 | www.test.at |   www.testR.at   |
| 6 | www.bann.at |   www.bannR.at   |
--------------------------------------
```

And I want the output look something like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|ID | ImageURLiOS | ImageURLiOSRetina | BannerImageURLiOS | BannerImageURLiOSRetina |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1 | www.test.at |   www.testR.at   |    www.bann.at     |      www.bannR.at       | 
| 2 | www.test.at |   www.testR.at   |    www.bann.at     |      www.bannR.at       | 
| 3 | www.test.at |   www.testR.at   |    www.bann.at     |      www.bannR.at       | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried some grouping and inner join but nothing really works.
Is it possible to accomplish that with SQL or do I have to do some PHP processing?

Comment: Multiple joins to the same table: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199953/how-do-you-join-on-the-same-table-twice-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select i.id, 
       u.iOSURL as ImageURLiOS,
       u.iOSRetinaURL as ImageURLiOSRetina, 
       ur.iOSURL as BannerImageURLiOS,
       ur.iOSRetinaURL as BannerImageURLiOSRetina 
from item i 
left join imageurl u on u.id = i.imageurlid
left join imageurl ur on ur.id = i.bannerimageurlid
```