# mysql multi join from same table give alias

Tags: mysql

currently i have the following query

```
SELECT * FROM tabs 
JOIN users d ON tabs.`debit` = d.id 
JOIN users c ON tabs.`credit` = c.id
```

as the table contains two user objects the names that get returned are the same like so:

```
id | amount | type | id | username | avatar | id | username | avatar
```

i need it to return as the following

```
 id | amount | type | debit.id | debit.username | debit.avatar | credit.id | credit.username | credit.avatar
```

or something simmilar as long as the column names from the users are prefixed.

Comment: You aren't selecting anything from debit and credit tables?

Comment: Debit and credit are not tables in this case. It needs to be a prefix for the user's columns. Since there are 2 users being joined.

Comment: You need to explicitly list the columns you want from users d and users c... and in the list you can specify the name you want with the AS.

Comment: Is there not a possibilty of easier automated. since there are alot of columns in the tables.

Comment: No. there isn't. I'd add that this question should be closed as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199953/how-do-you-join-on-the-same-table-twice-in-mysql.

Comment: My mistake but You aren't selecting anything other than tabs so that is all will show

Comment: @Frazz . . . It don't think it is a duplicate of that question.  Toby understands that two joins are needed.  S/he is just asking how to automatically rename the columns.

Comment: Ok, Gordon. The answer (to the original question) is very similar though. @Toby... maybe modify it and add what you have written in the comments (many columns, desire to do it automatically).

Comment: _“since there are alot of columns in the tables”_ – that is not a valid argument. You should not use `SELECT *` in any case, but rather specify the columns that you want. (And if those are “all of them”, then you _list_ all of them.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. Give it a try. (Assuming that `id | amount | type` belongs to the `tabs` table)

```
SELECT t.id,
t.amount,
t.type,
d.id as 'debit.id',
d.username as 'debit.username',
d.avatar as 'debit.avatar',
c.id as 'credit.id',
c.username as 'credit.username',
c.avatar as 'credit.avatar',
FROM tabs t
JOIN users d ON t.`debit` = d.id 
JOIN users c ON t.`credit` = c.id
```