# MySQL Show Result Twice Given Different Condition

Tags: mysql, magento

I have the following code which I'm using to get prices from a Magento database:

```
SELECT 
    `e`.`sku`, 
    `price_index`.`price` AS `RRP`, 
    `price_index`.`final_price` AS `Dealer Price`

FROM 
   `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` 

INNER JOIN 
`catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND
 price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 7
```

This works fine, however I need to get an additional price from "final_price" but with customer group 8 instead of 7 for example.

The results from my current script display:
SKU, RRP, Dealer Price

The Results I would like:
SKU, RRP, Dealer Price, Trader Price

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need left joins instead of inner joins. Note in the tested example below that I'm renaming the alias of price_index to price_index2 in the second join on the same table.

```
SELECT 
    `e`.`sku`, 
    `price_index`.`price` AS `RRP`, 
    `price_index`.`final_price` AS `Dealer Price`,
    `price_index2`.`final_price` AS `Trader Price`

FROM 
   `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` 

LEFT JOIN 
`catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND
 price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 7

LEFT JOIN
`catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index2` ON price_index2.entity_id = e.entity_id AND
 price_index2.website_id = '1' AND price_index2.customer_group_id = 8
```

Comment: Also a good example for reference of joining the same table multiple times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199953/how-do-you-join-on-the-same-table-twice-in-mysql

Comment: Works perfect, annoying thing is I tried something very similar to this, must of missed something simple. Thank you!