# Need to get the Field Value for 2 Fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have these 3 DB Tables

```
CityTable (List of Cities)
--------
CityCode
CityName


Advertiser (Profile of Advertisers)
----------
AdvertiserCode
AdvertiserName
CityCode


Ads (Transaction Table)
--------
AdsId
AdsTitle
AdsDesc
CityCode
AdvertiserCode
```

WHERE

```
Ads.CityCode is Where the Ads is being offered
Advertiser.CityCode is Address of the Advertiser
```

Using this query, I will only be able to get the City Name for the [`Ads`]

```
SELECT Ads.AdsTitle, Ads.AdsDesc, AdsCity, CityTable.CityName AS AdsCityName
FROM Ads
LEFT JOIN CityTable ON CityTable.CityCode = Ads.CityCode
LEFT JOIN Advertiser ON Advertiser.AdvertiserCode = Ads.AdvertiserCode
```

but I also need to get the [CityName] of the Advertiser

Comment: Part of the confusion is that your data is not normalized.  The `Advertiser` and `Ads` table have overlap.

Comment: There is no overlap. AdsCity is where they will offer the ads and AdvertiserTable is just a profile of the advertiser where AdvertiserCity is where is their Physical / Office Address

Comment: you need to join twice on CityTable using an alias (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199953/how-do-you-join-on-the-same-table-twice-in-mysql that's an old one so i have not marked as possible dupe)

Comment: Can you provide sample code please, I dont know how to use alias in Left Join

Comment: see the link above or ask googel

Comment: Sorry I have posted my comment before you added the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Ads.AdsTitle, Ads.AdsDesc, AdsCity, CityTable.CityName AS AdsCityName, AdvCity.CityName AS AdvertiserCity
FROM Ads
LEFT JOIN CityTable ON CityTable.CityCode = Ads.CityCode
LEFT JOIN Advertiser ON Advertiser.AdvertiserCode = Ads.AdvertiserCode
LEFT JOIN CityTable as AdvCity ON AdvCity.CityCode = Advertiser.CityCode
```