# SQL for ids from same table with relation defined in another table

Tags: mysql

I have employees in employees table, everyone has an employee code.
Few of them are managers, and one employee can have one manager id.
The relation is defined in employee details table. How do I get the employee_id and  manager_id
Below is the structure

```
employee
--------
id employee_id
1  CRG001
2  CRG002

employee_details
----------------
id employee_id manager
1  1            2
2  2            NULL
```

So what I want is if I want to enter CRG001 in an API and get the below structure

```
employee_id manager_id
CRG001      CRG002
```

and if I want to enter CRG002 in an API and get the below structure

```
employee_id manager_id
CRG002      NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple SELECT query, just need to [join on the employee table twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199953/how-do-you-join-on-the-same-table-twice-in-mysql):

```
SELECT e.employee_id AS employee_id, m.employee_id as manager_id
FROM employee_details d
LEFT JOIN employee e ON e.id = d.employee_id
LEFT JOIN employee m ON m.id = d.manager
WHERE e.employee_id = ?
```

See a dbfiddle with it working [<kbd>here</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sXzQps4WRzcKo1QzdkNgzm/0)

Comment: Thank you it worked fine as well. Got to know multiple ways to reach to the solution

Comment: @NitishPatra They're pretty much the same exact answer (Just with different aliases)

Comment: Oh i got carried away.. yeah both are same.. I was a little happy on getting the solution

Answer (score 1):

```
select e1.employee_id as employee_id, e2.employee_id as manager_id from employee e1
left join emloyee_details d on e1.id = d.employee_id
left join employee e2 on d.manager = e2.id
where e1.employee_id = 'CRG001'
```