# How to relate a table more than one time in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I want to relate two tables and a relation table. Tables are: `Person` with it's primary key named `id_person`, `Activity` with it's primary key named `id_activity` and a table that relates the previous two tables: `Activity_Person` that contain as primary and foreign keys `id_activity` and `id_person`.

To relate this tables using the old `JOIN` format this would work:

```
select * from activity, person, activity_person
where activity.id_activity = activity_person.id_activity and person.id_person = activity_person.id_person;
```

This would show the activities that each person has taken part on.

But now I'm learning about `JOIN`s and I don't know what's the correct format to relate a table that appears twice (`Activity_Person`).

I have tried this:

```
select * from 
person inner join activity_person on person.id_person = activity_person.id_person,
activity inner join activity_person on activity.id_activity = activity_person.id_activity;
```

But I get the following error:

> Not unique table/alias: 'activity_person'

What's the correct format?

Comment: This is a "self-join" & uses "aliases" aka "correlation names". This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you join on the same table, twice, in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199953/how-do-you-join-on-the-same-table-twice-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `activity_person` twice here. Just do

```
select *
    from person
    inner join activity_person on person.id_person = activity_person.id_person
    inner join activity on activity.id_activity = activity_person.id_activity;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want two joins:

```
select *
from person p inner join
     activity_person ap
     on p.id_person = ap.id_person inner join
     activity a
     on a.id_activity = ap.id_activity;
```

I'm not sure why you are trying to repeat `activity_person` in your query.

Also note that table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

Answer (score -1):

Your syntax is incorrect.

```
select * from activity, person, activity_person
where activity.id_activity = activity_person.id_activity
      and person.id_person = activity_person.id_person;
```

Is equivalent to :

```
select *
from person
inner join activity_person
on person.id_person = activity_person.id_person -- <- remove the comma there
inner join activity
on activity.id_activity = activity_person.id_activity;
```

Basically, the syntax is like this :

```
SELECT <the fields to select>
FROM <table name>
JOIN <table to join>
ON <joining condition>
-- if you want to add another table :
JOIN <new table to join>
ON <joining condition>
```