# MySQL SELECT two records from other table?

Tags: mysql

NOTE: This is not the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199953/how-do-you-join-on-the-same-table-twice-in-mysql), as I need to get data from two other records, not two fields from one one other record!

MySQL newb.  I have two tables, and I want to get data from both of them so I have the following:

wp_bowling_fixtures

```
fixture_id | fixture_date | home_team_id | away_team_id
-----------+--------------+--------------+-------------
1          | 2017-12-12   | 1            | 2
2          | 2017-12-12   | 3            | 4
3          | 2017-12-12   | 5            | 6
4          | 2017-12-12   | 7            | 8
5          | 2017-12-12   | 9            | 10
```

wp_bowling_teams

```
team_id | name   | division | archived
--------+--------+----------+---------
1       | Team A | 1        | 0
2       | Team B | 1        | 0
3       | Team C | 2        | 1
4       | Team D | 2        | 0
5       | Team E | 3        | 0
6       | Team F | 3        | 0
7       | Team G | 4        | 0
8       | Team H | 4        | 1
9       | Team I | 4        | 0
10      | Team J | 4        | 0
```

The result I want a SELECT query to produce:

```
fixture_id | fixture_date | home_team_id | home_team_name | home_team_archived | home_team_division | away_team_id | away_team_name | away_team_archived | away_team_division
-----------+--------------+--------------+----------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+----------------+--------------------+-------------------
1          | 2017-12-12   | 1            | Team A         | 0                  | 1                  | 2            | Team B         | 0                  | 1
```

I also want it ordered by fixture_date DESC, home_team_division ASC, home_team_name ASC.

Hope that makes sense.

TIA,

Nick.

Comment: I think this is exactly the same as the other question you linked to.

Comment: @EdmCoff The other question asks about getting two columns from one record.  I need to get data from two separate records.  I think that is different?

Comment: as @CaiusJard said, try to use INNER JOINS so you get data that exists in both tables. afterward, you can then use the WHERE condition if u want to filter out some data on some conditions. and on the end, you can use DESC, ASC to order the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT f.fixture_id, f.fixture_date, h.team_id as home_team_id, h.name as home_team_name, h.archived as home_team_archived, h.division as home_team_division, a.team_id as away_team_id, a.name as away_team_name, a.archived as away_team_archived, a.division as away_team_division FROM wp_bowling_fixtures f, wp_bowling_teams h, wp_bowling_teams a where f.home_team_id = h.team_id and f.away_team_id = a.team_id order by f.fixture_date desc, h.division asc, h.name asc;

Works.

Comment: Yea, this one is simpler than mine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in sql stops you joining a table twice but if you do so you must alias them .

You're looking for a query that uses

```
fixtures f 
JOIN teams h ON f.home_team_id = h.team_id
JOIN teams a ON f.away_team_id = a.team_id
```

I gave the teams `h` (for home) and `a` (for away) aliases so I could tell them apart. Give it a go at filling it out

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting there: SELECT * FROM wp_bowling_fixtures AS f 
JOIN wp_bowling_teams AS h ON f.home_team_id = h.team_id
JOIN wp_bowling_teams AS a ON f.away_team_id = a.team_id produces:     ["fixture_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["fixture_date"]=>
    string(19) "2020-01-01 00:00:00"
    ["home_team_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["away_team_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["team_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "Test Team 1b"
    ["division"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["archived"]=>
    string(1) "0"

Comment: Still missing the data from the second team (name etc).

Answer (score 0):

```
select x.fixture_id, x.fixture_date, x.home_team_id, x.home_team_name, x.home_team_archived, x.home_team_division,
y.away_team_id, y.away_team_name, y.away_team_archived, y.away_team_division from
(select a.fixture_id, a.fixture_date, a.home_team_id, b.name home_team_name, b.archived home_team_archived, b.division home_team_division
 from wp_bowling_fixtures a inner join wp_bowling_teams b on A.home_team_id = B.team_id) x
 inner join  
 (select a.fixture_id, a.fixture_date, a.away_team_id, b.name away_team_name, b.archived away_team_archived, b.division away_team_division
 from wp_bowling_fixtures a inner join wp_bowling_teams b on A.away_team_id = B.team_id) y on x.fixture_id = y.fixture_id
 order by x.fixture_date desc, home_team_division asc, home_team_name asc;`enter code here`
```