# How to implement many to many relation in view with following view, I want to display Employee & senctionBy from the same table in the view

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, sql-view

```
CREATE TABLE `leave_availed` (
      `LeaveID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `EmpID` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
       `levType` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
       `senctionBy` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
       .....
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE employee (
     empID int(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name varchar(100)
     ...
);

CREATE TABLE leavetype (
    id int(3) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `type` varchar(20) ,

);
```

I'm trying to create a view in which I want to see the actual data instead of ids so I created the following view called **view_leave** i.e. I want to display employee name twice in the view 1st for employee 2nd for boss(senctionBy)

[image: View_leave]

Comment: Both tables are called leave_availed? And why do you think this is a many to many relationship?(an employee can take many leaves to it's a one to many on the basis of what you have published so far) And you don't seem to care about leave entitlement. But this looks like a very simple 2 table join. Please add sample data and expected output as text to the question.

Comment: my bad, 2nd table is "employee" table. leave_availed table is linked in two columns with employee table. (1) empID refer to employee and 2nd is sanctionBy which is also employee (Boss)

Comment: IN that case you join the employee twice once for employee and once for senctionby. BTW senction is not an english word did you mean sanctionedBy

Comment: yes it is senctionBy mean senctionedBy

Comment: I just want to display employee name twice in view_leave one name for employee and 2nd for his boss(senctionedBy). How to implement it?. I searched for helped but unable to find right solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you join on the same table, twice, in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199953/how-do-you-join-on-the-same-table-twice-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You can join twice on the `employee` table. You seem to also want to avoid the leave types table.

```
create view v_leave_availed as 
select la.*, emp.name emp_name, boss.name section_by_name, lt.type leave_type
from leave_availed la
inner join employee emp on emp.empid = la.empid
inner join employee boss on boss.empid = la.senctionBy
inner join leavetype lt on lt.id = la.levtype
```