# Trouble with getting Self Joins to work with SQL project

Tags: php, sql, database

I have a webpage that allows me to display a table from my database that has library info, in this case, author full name, shelf location, book title, etc.  I have added first and last name to the database, in the same part as the author name, and I need to be able to display it in the same table with the other info.  I am struggling on how to get this to work, and my attempts at self joins have not worked well.  The author full name and first and last name parts all use the bookauthor.AID as their primary keys.

This is the code that I had before that works:

```
$sqlbook = $conn->prepare("SELECT Books.Title, Author.Author, BookLocation.PID, BookLocation.SID from Books LEFT JOIN BookAuthor on Books.BID=BookAuthor.BID LEFT JOIN Author on BookAuthor.AID=Author.AID RIGHT JOIN BookLocation ON Books.BID=BookLocation.BID where Author.Author like '%$search%'");
            /* $sqlbook->bindParam("s",$search); */
            $sqlbook->execute();
            $result = $sqlbook->get_result();
            $sqlbook->close();
            echo "<br><table class=\"results\">";
            echo 
                "<tr>
                    <th>Book Title</th>
                    <th>Author</th>
                    <th>Position on Shelf (0 front, 1 back)</th>
                    <th>Shelf Number</th>
                </tr>";
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<tr><td>" . $row["Title"] . "</td><td>" . $row["Author"]  . "</td><td>" . $row["PID"] . "</td><td>" . $row["SID"];
                    echo "</td></tr>\n";
                }
                echo "</table>";
```

And this is what I have now that is not currently working:

```
 $sqlbook = $conn->prepare("SELECT Books.Title, Author.Author, Author.ALast as ALast1, Author.AFirst as AFirst1, BookLocation.PID, BookLocation.SID from Books LEFT JOIN BookAuthor on Books.BID=BookAuthor.BID LEFT JOIN Author on BookAuthor.AID=Author.AID JOIN ALast on BookAuthor.AID=ALast1 JOIN AFirst on BookAuthor.AID=AFirst1 RIGHT JOIN BookLocation ON Books.BID=BookLocation.BID where Books.Title like '%$search%'");
            /* $sqlbook->bindParam("s","%" . $search . "%"); */
            $sqlbook->execute();
            $result = $sqlbook->get_result();
            $sqlbook->close();
            echo "<br><table class=\"results\">";
            echo 
                "<tr>
                    <th>Book Title</th>
                    <th>Author Full Name</th>
                    <th>Author Last Name</th>
                    <th>Author First Name</th>
                    <th>Position on Shelf (0 front, 1 back)</th>
                    <th>Shelf Number</th>
                </tr>";
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<tr><td>" . $row["Title"] . "</td><td>" . $row["Author"]  . "</td><td>" . $row["ALast"] . "</td><td>" . $row["AFirst"] . "</td><td>" . $row["PID"] . "</td><td>" . $row["SID"];
                    echo "</td></tr>\n";
                }
                echo "</table>";
```

Comment: When you join with the same table more than once you **must** use table aliases.

Comment: Alst1 is an alias for Author.ALast, i don't h getwhy you are using it for an JOIN that uses a alast table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you join on the same table, twice, in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199953/how-do-you-join-on-the-same-table-twice-in-mysql)

Comment: Is this question about SQL or about PHP?  Based on the SQL code it seems like it's about SQL.  If it's about SQL, please remove the PHP code to simplify the question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and remove the PHP tag.

Comment: Please provide sample input data and DDL to produce the tables and their values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you added the new columns (`ALast` and `AFirst`) to the `Author` table.  In that case, you don't need a self join.

```
SELECT Books.Title
, Author.Author
, Author.ALast
, Author.AFirst
, BookLocation.PID
, BookLocation.SID
from Books
  LEFT JOIN BookAuthor on Books.BID=BookAuthor.BID
  LEFT JOIN Author on BookAuthor.AID=Author.AID
  RIGHT JOIN BookLocation ON Books.BID=BookLocation.BID 
where Books.Title like '%$search%'
```

Comment: thank you so much, this worked, im not sure how i did not try this before